# How can I get the path to all music files on phones storage

Tags: react-native

It seems like a basic task but I can't find any useful tutorials for doing this with react native.

I want to get a list of paths of all the music files on my phone so I can play them.

Most music player app tutorials just load a music file from the web or simply mention 'path_to_file'. How can I get all the paths to music files stored on my phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the Expo.MediaLibrary?

As explained here: https://snack.expo.io/@jlorencelim/get-music-files

```
const media = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
   mediaType: MediaLibrary.MediaType.audio,
});
```

Comment: I didn't even know about it.

Comment: this shows that I don't have any audio files on my ios device which isn't true. I am using expo but running on my device - possibly that is an issue?